# iOS simulator build error with worklight, wikitude and sqlcipher framework

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, wikitude

I'm working with worklight, an augmented reality plugin called wikitude and a framework called sqlcipher. While I've got those working fine on iOS when building for a device or archive, when I attempt to build for the simulator there's a warning I've never seen followed by a multitude of duplicate symbol errors:

```
ld: warning: tentative definition of '_OPENSSL_ia32cap_P' with size 8 from '/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/Frameworks/sqlcipher.framework/sqlcipher(cryptlib.o)'
is being replaced by real definition of smaller size 4 from '/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/libWikitudeSDK.a(cryptlib.o)'
```

Then this error (truncated):

```
duplicate symbol _CRYPTO_THREADID_cmp in:
/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/Frameworks/sqlcipher.framework/sqlcipher(cryptlib.o)
/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/libWikitudeSDK.a(cryptlib.o)
.
.
.
duplicate symbol _OpenSSLDie in:
/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/Frameworks/sqlcipher.framework/sqlcipher(cryptlib.o)
/Users/mine/apps/wl/iphone/native/libWikitudeSDK.a(cryptlib.o)
ld: 33 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Wikitude is included in the project via the libWikitudeSDK.a and is in the link with libraries build phase, and sqlcipher is a .framework added in the same place. My other linker flags is set to -ObjC as when we used -all_load it caused the same duplicate symbol issue above between the wikitudeSDK and the worklightSDK.

I've followed the instructions from [this blog](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries) on how to avoid the duplicate error but while it fixes the one problem with cryptlib.o it just opens up hundreds of new duplicate symbol errors. I also tried lipo -arch_blank i386 when building a new library but that results only in Undefined symbols for architecture i386 errors.

To be clear, I'm not attempting to run the augmented reality component inside the simulator, I just want the to use the simulator to develop for the other aspects of my application which are not dependant on wikitude.

While removing wikitude from the project temporarily is an option, the versioning in the project just makes this a headache for all concerned and introduces an extra unneeded complexity.

Thank you in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see what version of Worklight you are using, but I assume it is pre-6.2.  In Worklight 6.2 the -all_load flag was replaced with a series of -force_load flags for specific libraries.

You could try using -force_load for specific libraries instead of -all_load.  There is a Technote for Worklight 6.1 describing how to do this: [Xcode linker options requirement to use FIPS 140-2 with IBM Worklight](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657759).  Since you are not using the FIPS 140-2 optional feature, you would not add the -force_load for libfipshttp.a; you would add a -force_load for both libCordova.a and libWorklightStaticLibProject.a and  remove -all_load as described.  Note that you may have to add -force_load for other libraries you are using if you get undefined symbols when linking.

For reference, here is a link describing the changes in Worklight 6.2 under the section [ios: Changes in Xcode linker options](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/devenv/c_upgrading_to_wl_studio_v610_migrating_projects.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Whoops, hit enter not shift+enter.
Sorry, I'm using WL 6.1.0. I switched the linker flags to use -force_load but now the I'm getting several hundred errors of the form:
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_TIFFClientOpen", referenced from:
      TIFFFdOpen(void*, char const*, char const*) in libWikitudeSDK.a(PluginTIFF.o)
      Open(FreeImageIO*, void*, int) in libWikitudeSDK.a(PluginTIFF.o)
      TIFFFdOpen(void*, char const*, char const*) in WikitudeSDK(PluginTIFF.o)
      Open(FreeImageIO*, void*, int) in WikitudeSDK(PluginTIFF.o)
`.

Comment: That looks like symbols references by WikitudeSDK, not Worklight.  You could try doing a force_load of that library also, or if there are other libraries it requires, you could try force_loading those.  Although that might also put you back where you started, with the duplicate symbols.